# Sharepoint SPService getListItem from an other list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint 2012 and the library SPService, JQuery .....

I have a list named project day

In this list, I have a dynamic form, and in this form, I have one dynamics field named Project.

In the display form, my project appear with ID.

This ID is the ID of the project in an other list named REF_PROJECTS.

When I 'm working with the display form of project day, I would like associate the ID with the ID of the other project.

REF_PROJECTS field :
ID
NAME
TITLE
CODE

So in the list project day, i would like to ask the list REF_PROJECTS, to find for example what is the name for the ID 335.

I have try like this : (at this time, i just want to see al items from REF-PROJECTS), but it didn't work

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

My website is like this

```
                                    INTRANET
```

REF_PROJECTS                            MYFORM                    OTHER 
                           FORM1    FORM2     project day

Do you have an idea how to view in this list all the informations from the other list ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, i'm using this script :   

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("test");

function test()
{

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "REF_PROJECTS",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
}

Comment: Re you sure you are using SharePoint 2012?

Answer (score 0):

The script you've posted doesn't seem to have much to do with what you are describing you want. You need to use the right listName, for example. You should also add a CAMLQuery clause to filter for the ID you want, probably by grabbing it from the URL.